# If I use a { get; set; } on a field in a Global class, will that get/set be public or global?

Tags: apex, global-variables, getter, setter, global

If I have a class that is global and I use the getter setter implementation:

`Integer myInt { get; private set; }`

Will my variable `myInt` be a global or a public variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the access modifier for the property itself using syntax as covered in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_properties.htm):

```
public class BasicClass {
   // Property declaration
   access_modifier return_type property_name {
      get {
         //Get accessor code block
      }
      set {
         //Set accessor code block
      }
   } 
}
```

Note the *access_modifier* before the *return_type* of the *property_name*.

The documentation goes on to discuss how you can use access modifiers on property accessors:

> If an accessor includes its own access modifier, this modifier overrides the access modifier of the property. The access modifier of an individual accessor must be more restrictive than the access modifier on the property itself. For example, if the property has been defined as public, the individual accessor can’t be defined as global.

Returning to your example, since you haven't provided an access modifier for the property then it defaults to `private`. Thus `myInt` is entirely private (the getter is private implicitly and the setter is private explicitly).

Methods and properties do not inherit the access modifier of the class. The only exception to this are default/inherited constructors (like on `Exception` subclasses) and methods on an interface.